# Save a decision tree model in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm building a decision tree using Scikit-Learn in Python. I've trained the model on a particular dataset and now I want to save this decision tree so that it can be used later (on a new dataset). Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

As taken from the Model Persistence section of [this tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html):

It is possible to save a model in the scikit by using Python’s built-in persistence model, namely [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html):

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> X, y = iris.data, iris.target
>>> clf.fit(X, y)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(clf)
>>> clf2 = pickle.loads(s)
>>> clf2.predict(X[0])
array([0])
>>> y[0]
0
```

Comment: That's cool. So when I save the DT into the pickle file, it stores all the structure and can be re-used again. That's really nice.

Anything for R too?

Comment: Got it for what to do in R to save robjects. Once can you the save command to save the objects to a file and then use the load command to read back.

More details about the save command can be found [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)

Info about load command can be found at [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html)

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no reliable way of doing this. While pickling does work, it is not good enough, as your pickled data is not guaranteed to get properly unpickled with a later version of scikit-learn.

Quote from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations

> Models saved in one version of scikit-learn might not load in another
>   version.

Answer (score 4):

I used `joblib` as below:

```
>>> from joblib import dump, load
>>> dump(clf, 'filename.joblib')
>>> clf = load('filename.joblib')
```

However, need to consider [these](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations) security and maintainability limitations.